# How can I install Windows OS to my netbook with Android OS?

Tags: windows, android, netbook

I've got a netbook with Android OS and I want to install Windows XP for this. Is it possible and how can I install it? I don't find Bios (or boot Menu)  (Sorry for my bad English, I'm not native English).

Comment: To find out if it's possible, it would be helpful to know the name of the netbook :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless your netbook has an x86 or x64 variety CPU, and all the relevant hardware drivers are available, you won't be able to install Windows.